# Deserialization "[]" json as empty list

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have a class with `List<BigInteger>` listField. JSON part for this field looks like `"listField":"[]"`. I use the following piece of code for deserialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass myClass = mapper.readValue(jsonAsString, MyClass.class);
```

But an exception is thrown:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

fasterxml.jackson version 2.2.3

Could you help me please how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Why is the JSON field `"listField":"[]"` rather than `"listField":[]` ?

Comment: @khelwood, it is the server response. Is it wrong json?

Comment: `[]` is an empty array in JSON. `"[]"` is a string containing two brackets. It's wrong if you were expecting it to be an array.

Comment: @khelwood, you are right. Server side have `@JsonSerialize(using = ToStringSerializer.class)` annotation. But can i retrieve list from this string value?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to custom deserializer it is possible to add new setter and ignore old. It helps me.

```
    @JsonProperty("listField")
    public void setListFieldAsString(String listFieldAsString) {
        List<BigInteger> listFieldAsList = new ArrayList<BigInteger>();

        try {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            listFieldAsList = objectMapper.readValue(listFieldAsString, new TypeReference<List<BigInteger>>() {});
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error was detected!");
        }
        setListField(listFieldAsList);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setListField(List<BigInteger> listField) {
        this.listField = listField;
    }
```